# Prove the following using the Wilson's Theorem

Tags: elementary-number-theory, congruences

> Given a prime number, $p$, prove that $(p-1)!\equiv p-1\,\,\left(\text{mod }\frac{p(p-1)}2\right)$

How do we modify the Wilson's theorem into modulo $p(p-1)/2$ ? 
I can't get any clue

[(original image)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KLOgG.jpg)

Comment: You can prove it mod $p$, and prove it mod $(p-1)/2$, and then note those two moduli are relatively prime.

Comment: @Gerry Myerson thanks I got it !!!!!!!!

Comment: Good. Let me encourage you to write it up and post it as an answer.

Comment: @Gerry Myerson First we prove when p=2. And, (p-1)! = p-1 (mod p) by Wilson, and (p-1)! = p-1 = 0 (mod (p-1)/2) because (p-1)! has (p-1)/2 as factor since p is odd. Then since gcd((p-1)/2 , p) = 1, the above holds. Right?

Comment: So, post it as an answer.

Comment: @GerryMyerson: not only can we prove it mod $(p-1)/2$, we can prove it mod $p-1$, which is stronger.

Comment: @rob, sure, so the original congruence in fact holds modulo $p(p-1)$.

Answer (score 3):

Start with Wilson's Theorem
$$
(p-1)!\equiv-1\pmod{p}
$$
Since $(p,p-1)=1$, we can divide by $p-1\equiv-1\pmod{p}$ to get
$$
(p-2)!\equiv1\pmod{p}
$$
Multiply by $p-1$ to get
$$
(p-1)!\equiv p-1\pmod{p(p-1)}
$$
which implies that
$$
(p-1)!\equiv p-1\,\,\,\left(\text{mod }\frac{p(p-1)}2\right)
$$

Answer (score 2):

$(p\!-\!1)!-(p\!-\!1)\, $ is divisible by coprimes $\,p\!-\!1\,$ and $\,p\,$ (by Wilson), so is divisible by $\,(p\!-\!1)p$

Comment: To be completely rigorous, the final inference follows either by unique factorization, or by using $\ a,b\mid c\,\Rightarrow\,{\rm lcm}(a,b)\mid c,\,$ and $\,(a,b)=1\,\Rightarrow\, {\rm lcm}(a,b) = ab.\ \ $

Answer (score 0):

We can divide by $p-1$. So, we only need to prove that $(p-2)!\equiv1 \pmod{p/2}$.

And multiply by $2$, for $p>2$. So, we only need to prove that $2(p-2)!\equiv 2 \pmod p$.

By Wilson $(p-1)!\equiv -1$. Then $-(p-2)!\equiv (p-1)(p-2)!\equiv -1$.

Hence $(p-2)!\equiv 1$.

Comment: If p is odd, then p/2 is not an integer.

Comment: So, better to divide by $(p-1)/2$.

Comment: @user220927 That doesn't matter. Remember that congruences are really an equality when you add a multiple of the modulus. You can do all those operations on the equality if the non-integer modulus makes you uncomfortable.